# Mozilla appearance Checkbox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, checkbox, mozilla

i'm trying to personalize the appearance of Checkbox but this only works in Google Chrome for mozilla doesn't work i dont know how to fix this here is my code:

Example:

[Checkbox on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/r9cf4y7b/)

> **¡Please!** before you post any response see example in the 2 browsers in
>   this case Chrome and Mozilla.

images from google chrome and mozilla

Chrome:

[image: Visual fixed]

Mozilla

[image: mozilla fxck....]

CSS:

```
#div-tallas .seleccion-talla .btn-default{
padding: 6px 7px;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 1.2em;
letter-spacing: 0px;
min-width: 40px;
margin-left: 1px !important;
}
#div-tallas input[type="checkbox"] {
/* 1 */
display: inline-block;
height: 36px;
width: 36px;
border: 2px solid #000;
-moz-border: 2px solid #000;
/* 2 */
overflow: hidden;
/* 3 */
margin-top: -4px;
vertical-align: middle;
/* 4 */
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
outline: 0;
/* 5 */
background: #e5e4e4;
-moz-background: #e5e4e4;
}
/*
* Checked
*/
#div-tallas input[type=checkbox]:checked {
/* 1 */
display: inline-block;
height: 36px;
width: 36px;
border: 2px solid #e5e4e4 !important;
-moz-border: 2px solid #e5e4e4 !important;
/* 2 */
overflow: hidden;
/* 3 */
margin-top: -4px;
vertical-align: middle;
/* 4 */
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
outline: 0;
/* 5 */
background: #ff6500 !important;
background-color: #ff6500 !important;
padding: 2px;
transition: background 0.4s linear 0s, color 0.4s linear 0s;
}
/* Checkbox */
#div-tallas input[type=checkbox]:checked:before,
#div-tallas input[type=checkbox]:indeterminate:before {
content: "\f00c";
font-family: FontAwesome;
font-size: 32px;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
text-align: center;
line-height: 26px;
color: #e5e4e4;
z-index: 888;
margin-left: -1px;
}
#div-tallas input[type=checkbox]:indeterminate:before {
content: "\f068";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about styling the label?

```
#div-tallas {
   background-color: #e5e4e4 !important;
   min-height: 40vh;
}
#div-tallas input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
#div-tallas input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    padding-left: 0;
}
#div-tallas input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  /* 1 */
  font: 32px/32px 'FontAwesome';
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: transparent;
  /* &nbsp; to show content */
  content: "\00a0";
  margin-right: 8px;
}

/*
 * Checked
 */
#div-tallas input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  background: #ff6500;
  transition: background 0.4s linear 0s, color 0.4s linear 0s;
}

/* Checkbox */
#div-tallas input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before,
#div-tallas input[type=checkbox]:indeterminate + label:before {
  content: "\f00c";
  color: #e5e4e4;
}
#div-tallas input[type=checkbox]:indeterminate + label:before {
  content: "\f068";
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/theoshu/ncLptbfq/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't 100% perfect but it does show you a working example of a pure CSS checkbox that works in both Chrome and Firefox.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fp8axzbd/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="div-tallas">
  <div class="quiero-este"> 
  <h5>¡Quiero este!</h5>
    <div class="checkbox check-primary m-top-40 text-center">
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkbox1" />
      <label for="checkbox1"></label>
    </div>                                              
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#div-tallas {
  background-color: #e5e4e4 !important;
  min-height: 40vh;
}

#div-tallas input[type=checkbox] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#div-tallas input[type=checkbox],
#div-tallas input[type=checkbox] + label::before {
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
#div-tallas input[type=checkbox] + label::before {
  content: '';
  text-align: center;
  background: #e5e4e4;
  display: inline-block;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 1;
  color: black;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}
#div-tallas input[type=checkbox] + label {
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
}
#div-tallas input[type=checkbox]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#div-tallas input[type=checkbox]:hover + label::before {
  content: '';
  background: #e5e4e4;
}
#div-tallas input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::before {
  background: #ff6500 !important;
  background-color: #ff6500 !important;
  outline: 0;
  content: "\f00c";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 32px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 26px;
  color: #e5e4e4;
  z-index: 888;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
#div-tallas input[type=checkbox]:checked:hover + label::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It looks exactly like your picture and works in both browsers. What's not correct?

Comment: I didn't copy your CSS 100%, this was just meant as a demo to get you on the right track. I'm not writing every last bit of code for you or you'll just copy/paste without learning anything. Sorry!